# Simulate invalid HTTP request

Tags: node.js, nginx

I need to simulate malformed HTTP requests to my server for testing purposes - I have a [clientError](https://nodejs.org/api/http.html#http_event_clienterror) handler in my Node.js server and want to create a functional test it.

For example:
`curl "https://myhost/endpoint?term=one two"` will trigger this handler (due to the not encoded space between words `one` and `two`)

I'm struggling to find a way to do a similar request in Node. As far as I know, any kind of higher level request libraries do encoding automatically so I couldn't use them.

Using the built-in `net` library instead I managed to get this far:

```
const net = require('net');
const socket = new net.Socket();

const options = {
    port: 443,
    host: 'myhost'
};

socket.connect(options, () => {
    console.log('connected to', socket.remoteAddress);
    socket.write('GET /endpoint?term=one two HTTP/1.1\r\n' +
    'Host: myhost\r\n' +
    '\r\n');

socket.on('data', (data) => {
    console.log('SOCKET RESPONSE: ' + data);
}).on('end', () => {
    console.log('SOCKET ENDED');
});
```

The problem is, calls to my Node.js service are proxied through Nginx, so running the above code results in 400 error from Nginx:

> The plain HTTP request was sent to HTTPS port

I see using `--verbose` flag that Curl is smart enough to make some TLS handshakes.

Any ideas how to update my code to achieve this?

Comment: Well, if your server is served through Nginx, your clientError will never handle malformed URL error, since Nginx will. You don't need to test that case, right? To test other possible errors, I would do it by testing your logic inside the handler, instead of forcing an error.

Comment: @Héctor nginx tries to proxy the example Curl request to Node service. If there is no clientError handler, then you'll see a "upstream" error in nginx (because socket is just closed) and as a client you'll get 502. If you have the handler in the service, then you can respond from the service with appropriate code, like 400. This is how it works for us.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution was to use the `tls` library:

```
const tls = require('tls');

const options = {
    port: 443,
    host: 'myhost'
};
const socket = tls.connect(options, () => {
    console.log('connected to', socket.remoteAddress);
    socket.write('GET /endpoint?term=one two HTTP/1.1\r\n' +
        'Host: myhost\r\n' +
        '\r\n');

    socket.setEncoding('utf8');
    socket.on('data', data => {
        console.log('SOCKET RESPONSE:', data);
    }).on('end', () => {
        console.log('Connection end');
    }).on('close', (had_error) => {
        console.log('Connection closed. Had error:', had_error);
    }).on('error', error => {
        console.log('ERROR:', error);
    });
});
```